# DisplayLayered Navigation based on root category on homepage

Tags: xml, magento2, layered-navigation

In Magento1 there is a possibility to display layered navigation on the homepage through a layout update XML in the design tab of any CMS page.

Since layered navigation is based on the page category, I want the layered navigation on the homepage to be based on the root category (that is set as "anchor").

Is there a way to perform this in Magento2 via the design update XML tab?

Answer (score 2):

you can have category list widget and add the widget to your desired location

Category List Widget : https://store.emizentech.com/magento2/category-list-widget.html

you can update the layout as per your needs in module phtml files

Comment: Looks interesting. Let me try it since the description is not that clear. I will comment once installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to install the extension. Do you have a demo available? Github says: Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.

Comment: Tried to order an install via your website. Not possible. Also have sent you a private message. Did you see that?